# XPage not found because database name is in uppercase

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

We have inherited a web application in Lotus Notes in which we are trying to introduce XPages (we are new to both Lotus Notes and XPages, please forgive our inexperience).

We have a view that we are trying to swap with an XPage. The current view is called like this from the application menu (the view is being called from a form):

```
<a href="FRVWFACSPROVXEstadoAno?openform" target="ifat">
```

And we are trying to call the XPage like this:

```
<a href="Prueba.xsp" target="ifat">
```

For some reason, the link is expanded at runtime to this:

```
http://tbsdesa.es.lladro.com/FORMACION/CARLOS/TBS_AGORA_FIN.NSF/Prueba.xsp
```

The page is not found because the database name is in uppercase (in fact, if we change TBS_AGORA_FIN.NSF to TBS_AGORA_FIN.nsf, it works). It is also strange that the current link is in uppercase, too, but nevertheless it works:

```
http://tbsdesa.es.lladro.com/FORMACION/CARLOS/TBS_AGORA_FIN.NSF/FRVWFACSPROVXEstadoAno?openform
```

We would like to know why the database is in uppercase. Could the Domino server be doing this?

Comment: Please, add the missing code parts. Mark the code parts and click "{}" then the code will be shown in read mode too.

Comment: Second link is native Domino link, which ignores case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume based on your question that you're calling your link from a form or page that's rendering as HTML. Since it's a relative link, you're probably navigating to it through a link that includes uppercase for the .NSF in the title. This can be solved either by fixing all your links so that .nsf is lowercase, or by calculating your XPages links better.

To do the latter, I usually do the following for XPage Links:

```
<a href="<Computed Value>XPage.xsp">Link</a>
```

Where XPage.xsp is the name of my xpage and the value of the Computed Text is:

```
"/" + @WebDbName + "/"
```

This will calculate the link based on what Notes wants to refer to the database as.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Yes, I am calling the link from a form rendered as html. The computed value solution works, but I had to force it to be lowercase: "/" + @LowerCase(@WebDbName) + "/". I will try to figure out why @WebDbName returns the database name in uppercase, but in the meantime it works. Thanks!

Comment: It could be something as simple as the filename of the database is in capital letters. Try creating a new copy and renaming the file, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

What OS is the server running on? If the server is running on Linux/Unix then you need to be aware that directories and filenames are case sensitive. The tricky thing, however, is that once they have been opened they are cached by the server - and will work without being case sensitive (for some time...). This can be really tricky to troubleshoot if you are not aware of the cause ;-)

I agree with the possible solution suggested by Aaron, however, it really should not be necessary... It should be better to leave that to the server.

If you are running on a *nix OS then ensuring that all paths and filenames are in the same case (I use lowercase) is a good practice...

/John

Comment: No, this is a Windows server. Thanks for the suggestion, though.